# Push_back map into vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

How can I push_back a `std::map` element into `std::vector`?

```
std::vector<std::map<int, int>> v;

// Error
v.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 1))
```

What cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
v.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 1))
```

is a problem since a `std::pair` cannot be converted to a `std::map`. You can resolve the problem using one of the following methods that I can think of.

**Method 1**

If you can use a C++11 compiler,

```
v.push_back({{0, 1}});
```

**Method 2**

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
v.push_back(m);
```

**Method 3**

```
std::map<int, int> m;
v.push_back(m);
v.back().insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
```

Comment: What does `{{ }}` do?

Comment: @user963241, It can construct a `std::map` using the `initialization_list`. E.g. you can use `std::map<int, int> m{{0, 1}};` to construct a `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::map<int, int>> v;
```

means you are declaring vector of maps!

`push_back` a map into vector, like this

```
v.push_back({std::make_pair(0, 1)}); //Needs C++11
```

OR

```
std::map<int, int> map1;
map1.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
v.push_back(map1);
```

`push_back`'ng a `pair` will obviously result into a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can push a map into your Data Structure, `std::vector<std::map<int, int>> v`. not a pair i.e. element of map.

So, do as following.

```
std::map<int,int> t;
t.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
v.push_back(t);
```

or in case of C++11

```
v.push_back({{1,2}});
```

Or alternatively you can go for emplace_back too.

```
void emplace_work_around(
    std::vector<std::map<int, int>>& v,
    std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int,int>> item
 )
 {
    v.emplace_back(item);
 }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<int, int>> v;

    emplace_work_around(v,{{1,2}});
}
```